# Usar archivo json para hacer logs en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, logger, log

estoy iniciandome en python y estoy trabajando en un pequeño proyecto para generar diferentes reportes y uno de los que quiero generar es con loggin. tengo un archivo json el cual tiene ciertos datos y me gustaria usarlos como para interactuar con python y generar un log de acuerdo a ciertos datos.
primero muestro los datos de my json file:

```
{
  "services": [
    {
      "name": "ac",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "running",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "20%"
    },
    {
      "name": "acc",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "running",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "63%"
    },
    {
      "name": "acv",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "running",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "37%"
    },
    {
      "name": "acf",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "running",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "48%"
    },
    {
      "name": "ach",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "error",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "10%"
    },
    {
      "name": "acj",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "stopped",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "23%"
    },
    {
      "name": "acq",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "running",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "65%"
    },
    {
      "name": "bc",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "stopped",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "20%"
    },
        {
      "name": "bcc",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "running",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "25%"
    },
    {
      "name": "bcx",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "error",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "4%"
    },
    {
      "name": "bcn",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "running",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "50%"
    },
    {
      "name": "bcm",
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "service": "stopped",
      "url": "https://portal.azure.com/#home",
      "disk usage": "35%"
    }
  ]
}
```

he creado una parte del codigo para generar un archivo log y le he seteado algunos mensajes, lo que no se como hacer es por ejemplo si el uso del disco es mayor a 40% salga un warning o si es mayor a 50% tire algun error o critical.

```
import logging
import json

# Logger configuration
LOG_FORMAT = "%(levelname)s %(asctime)s - %(message)s"
logging.basicConfig(filename= r"C:\Users\Maximiliano\Documents\TrainingProject\Monitoring.log",
                    level= logging.DEBUG, 
                    format=LOG_FORMAT, 
                    filemode='w')
logger = logging.getLogger()

#Messages
logger.debug("Debuggin services...")
logger.info("The service is health")
logger.warning("A service reboot will be good")
logger.error("Some Services are not working correctly")
logger.critical("service DOWN!!!")

#set up json file
def get_data():
    with open('services.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        return data

data = get_data()
```

agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el fondo supongo que estás preguntando cómo iterar sobre los datos que has leido y cómo extraer el uso de disco. Una vez tienes eso, compararlo con ciertos valores umbral y emitir los mensajes es algo trivial.

Tu variable `data` es un diccionario que en su clave `"services"` tiene una lista. Puedes iterar por esa lista y en cada iteración obtendrás un diccionario que representa un servicio. En la clave `"name"` de ese diccionario tienes el nombre, y en la clave `"disk usage"` tienes el porcentaje de uso. Este porcentaje es más útil como número de punto flotante, para poder compararlo o hacer operaciones con él. Basta eliminar el último carácter de la cadena (que es el tanto por ciento) y convertir a `float` lo que queda.

Usando estas ideas, sería algo como lo siguiente:

```
for s in data["services"]:
  du = float(s["disk usage"][:-1])
  if 50 < du:
    logger.error(f'Service {s["name"]} disk usage {du}%')
  elif 40 < du < 50:
    logger.warning(f'Service {s["name"]} disk usage {du}%')
```

La expresión `s["disk usage"][:-1]` es la que elimina el último caracter (el porcentaje) usando una *slice* que toma desde el inicio, hasta el carácter -1 (en python los índices negativos se cuentan desde el final).

Con el JSON que has proporcionado en la pregunta este código mostraría algo similar a:

```
ERROR: Service acc disk usage 63.0%
WARNING: Service acf disk usage 48.0%
ERROR: Service acq disk usage 65.0%
```

Comment: creo que esto me podría ayudar si si , al copiar este codigo me da un error en la parte del json
```
#set up json file
def get_data():
    with open('services.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        return data
data = get_data()
```
en el data=json.load(f) me dice que es un undefined variable

Comment: ¿Cuál es la variable no definida? Pero por otro lado ese código era el que tú ya dabas en tu pregunta, y supuse que la lectura del json te funcionaba correctamente.

Comment: Ignora el error, si darme cuenta borre el import json

Comment: funciono como esperaba y necesitaba, muchas gracias