# colores en tabla en pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, matplotlib

tengo un código de python en con archivo json que me genera un grafico de pandas, lo que quiero hacer es que cuando la barra del grafico pasa cierto porcentaje esa barra cambie de color... por ejemplo si pasa los 40 que sea amarrillo pero si pasa los 60 que sea rojo, es posible? comparto un poco de mi código para poder hacerlo

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import json

#set up json file
def get_data():
    with open('services.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        return data
data = get_data()


df = pd.DataFrame(data["services"])
print(df)

df["disk usage"] = df["disk usage"].str[:-1].astype(float)

df.plot(x="name", kind="bar")
plt.show()
```

y este es el grafico:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

agradezco su ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre lo siguiente.

Primero añadimos a tu dataframe tres columnas adicionales, que contendrán respectivamente los valores menores de 40, los  que están entre 40 y 60 y los mayores de 60. A estas nuevas columnas les daré por nombre `"du<40"`, `"40<du<60"` y `"du>60"` respectivamente. En cada una de esas columnas sólo habrá datos en las celdas que cumplan las condiciones, y habrá `None` en las que no lo cumplan.

Se entendrá mejor con el código y viendo el resultado:

```
df["du>60"] = df["disk usage"].where(df["disk usage"].between(60, 100), None)
df["40<du<60"] = df["disk usage"].where(df["disk usage"].between(40, 60), None)
df["du<40"] = df["disk usage"].where(df["disk usage"].between(0, 40), None)
```

El `where` sirve para especificar qué filas vamos a copiar a esa nueva columna, y serán sólo las que cumplan la condición, en este caso que "disk usage" esté entre dos valores dados a través de `.between()`. Las que no lo cumplan recibirán el valor `None`.

Tras hacer esto tu dataframe quedará así (los datos los he tomado de [esta otra pregunta tuya](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/422168/usar-archivo-json-para-hacer-logs-en-python) en la que mostrabas el json que estás cargando)

```
   name version  service  ... du>60  40<du<60 du<40
0    ac   1.0.8  running  ...  None      None    20
1   acc   1.0.8  running  ...    63      None  None
2   acv   1.0.8  running  ...  None        47  None
3   acf   1.0.8  running  ...  None        48  None
4   ach   1.0.8    error  ...  None      None    10
5   acj   1.0.8  stopped  ...  None        43  None
6   acq   1.0.8  running  ...    65      None  None
7    bc   1.0.8  stopped  ...  None      None    20
8   bcc   1.0.8  running  ...  None      None    25
9   bcx   1.0.8    error  ...  None      None     4
10  bcn   1.0.8  running  ...  None        45  None
11  bcm   1.0.8  stopped  ...  None      None    35
```

Ves aquí las tres columnas añadidas, y cómo tienen None en la mayoría de lugares. Por ejemplo, la última fila (11) tenía como valor original 35, y ya que éste valor es menor de 40, se copió a la columna "du<40", y en las otras dos hay None.

Una vez hemos preparado el dataframe de este modo, podemos ahora hacer tres `plot()`, uno para cada una de estas nuevas columnas, especificando el color deseado para cada uno de esos grupos. Para que los tres plots vayan a la misma gráfica, recogemos el valor `ax` devuelto por la primera de ellas y se lo pasamos como parámetro `ax` a las otras dos (se trata de los "axes" en los que la gráfica será pintada):

```
ax = df.plot(x="name", y="du<40", kind="bar", color="royalblue")
df.plot(x="name", y="40<du<60", kind="bar", color="gold", ax=ax)
df.plot(x="name", y="du>60", kind="bar", color="tomato", ax=ax)
```

y la gráfica resultante es:

[image: Resultado]